# Wrong output in printf

Tags: c, syntax, logic

I'm new to C and trying to learn as best I can. I have this problem which I solved and the logic works pretty good, but whenever there is a wrong input it shows the message on screen and plus that the condition is not true. So whenever there is supposed to be an Invalid Input message I also get NE - which is what it would print out if the condition isn't true.

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int a, b;
    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
    if(a <= 0 || b <= 0) {
        printf("Invalid input");
    } else {
        if(a < b) {
            int tmp = a;
            a = b;
            b = tmp;
        }
    }
    a/=10;
    int c1,c2;
    while (a!=0 && b!=0){
        c1 = a%10;
        c2 = b%10;
        a /= 100;
        b /= 10;
    }
    if (c1 == c2)
        printf("PAREN\n");
    else
        printf ("NE\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you `return 1` after `printf("Invalid input");`? That way it won't print `NE`.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what the valid inputs are, and why are the resulting outputs either PAREN or NE?

Comment: To indicate that the problem is solved, you should click the checkmark to the left of the answer that helped you.

Comment: @Mike The valid inputs are all integers bigger than 0. And the output says PAREN if the digits of the small number are located in the even placed digits of the bigger number,reading from right to left.

Comment: Please do not edit your question to include "SOLVED,". If any of the answers actually provided the answer, you can mark it as accepted - that's all. If none of them did and you found the answer yourself, you can submit your own solution as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Its because there is nothing thats stop it to do so:

If you just want to terminate your program just `return` whenever if condition is true:

```
if(a <= 0 || b <= 0) {
printf("Invalid input");
return 1;
 }
```

Alternative: Just add rest of the code under `else` clause.

Comment: You probably should return a non-zero value since it's a fail.

Comment: @wrangler Thanks a lot! that worked.And whats more important i learned something new :) .

Answer (score 1):

Either you add a `return` statement as suggested in other answers, or you **include everything that should happen for valid input in the first `else` clause** (in other words, just move the closing brace of the first `else` clause, just before the closing brace of your `main` function.)

Comment: You don't need to edit the question with a "solved" mention. Just accept the answer that best addresses your problem.

Comment: I see you edited your question and removed your "solved" mention... but still you haven't accepted one answer to close the subject. Just click on the 'tick' left to the answer you decide to mark as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's reformat the code so it is easier to see the control flow:

```
int main()
{
    int a, b;
    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
    if(a <= 0 || b <= 0) {
        printf("Invalid input");
    } else {
        if(a < b) {
            int tmp = a;
            a = b;
            b = tmp;
        }
    }
    a/=10;
    int c1,c2;
    while (a!=0 && b!=0){
        c1 = a%10;
        c2 = b%10;
        a /= 100;
        b /= 10;
    }
    if (c1 == c2)
        printf("PAREN\n");
    else
        printf ("NE\n");
    return 0;
}
```

What's happening here is that when it prints "Invalid Input" the program continues running.  From here it can either print "PAREN" or "NE".

I suspect what you actually want to do is to stop processing once you've determined that the input is invalid.

The simplest way to do this in your code would be to add "return 0;" immediately after the "printf("Invalid input");" line.